# remove a html element by attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to delete an element whose attribute `cursor = "pointer".`. I need do it with javascript in html 
The item in question is this `<g cursor="pointer"></g>`.
I dont know the reason why the element has this form in html.

Comment: @gdoron - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/g-element.html

Comment: @bPratik. That's new, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('g[cursor="pointer"]').remove();
```

Comment: @gdoron I have a vague memory that not all browsers can "see" into SVG structures; it's as if they're not really part of the DOM. I could be completely wrong however.

Comment: @Pointy, so, is there other ways?(if the vague memory didn't mislead you)

Comment: I'm trying to determine whether I'm remembering correctly - I'll add a comment when I figure it out :-)

Comment: I think I must be thinking of something else - [this simple test suggests that it should work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/rVmTb/)